Arthurian stage play that had The 5th Dimension's "Up, Up and Away" played during a flying scene with Merlin
I was putting my child to bed tonight and, when he was saying "Up" repeatedly, it led to me suddenly remembering watching a stage show at the Paramount Arts Center in Ashland, KY.
I don't remember exactly when it was other than that it must have been before 1998, and I suspect it was around 1990-1992 because I remember "Up, Up and Away" coming up in a trivia game in Middle School and me remembering seeing the show.
The show was focused on Arthur and Merlin, I think as Merlin taught him to become the king. Only two scenes have remained in my head over three decades, though. The first was a scene with the aforementioned song. Merlin was giving Arthur experiences via magic, I believe in this case turning him into a bird to fly. I remember that the Merlin character held his cape up as if they were wings (with something stiff in the edges to allow them to spread) and he and Arthur moved around stage as if they were flying (I don't remember Arthur having a cape that he spread for the scene) while the song played. I think I remember, at the time, being a bit literal about it, and assuming that the song meant that Merlin was busting out a balloon to teach Arthur about flight, but I think they were supposed to be transformed.
The other scene was him teaching Arthur swordplay. At the time, my brother had a friend who'd introduced him to "boffer" swords made of PVC pipe surrounded by insulation and then wrapped in duct-tape, and I remember the swords looking like that, but I don't know if that's because they were, or because I just had firm ideas of how swordwork functioned, which involved the swords being like that.
I remember the fight choreography as being clashing swords, flynning with two-handed longsword length weapons, but not much more. Another detail that vaguely sticks in my head was the Merlin's robe looked like it was made of multiple patches rather than a single contiguous piece of cloth.
As with my other question about a theatrical play I saw as a child, there is a real possibility that what I watched was a student play that never saw a broader exposure, but I figured it was worth putting out what I recalled to see if perhaps someone remembers it.

If no one here can help you, I recommend asking librarians at the Ashland Public Library. A lot of times they'll just go look for you, but if not they'll at least have newspapers on microfiche or scanned into a database that you can search for whatever was showing at the time and place you remember.
